# use CrmServiceClient by Oauth fail with my own AppId

Tags: azure, oauth, dynamics-crm, crm, powerapps

I am using the `CrmServiceClient` from `Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly` nuget package. Since the deprecation of `Office365` auth type, I need to move to OAuth.

The question is when I use the AppId from MS, my code works, once when I use my own AppId, my code fails.

Here is my code:

```
//AppId and RedirectUri from MS, this works
var cli = new CrmServiceClient("AuthType=OAuth;Username=someemail@xxx.onmicrosoft.com;Password=secret;Url=https://orgname.crm5.dynamics.com;AppId=51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d;RedirectUri=app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97;LoginPrompt=Never");
//AppId from my onw app, this fail
var cliFromMyApp = new CrmServiceClient("AuthType=OAuth;Username=someemail@xxx.onmicrosoft.com;Password=secret;Url=https://orgname.crm5.dynamics.com;AppId=myappid;RedirectUri=app://myappid;LoginPrompt=Never");
```

MS AppId and RedirectUri are from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect#connection-string-parameters)

My app looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I have granted this app with Crm and dataverse privileges.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your account configured for 2-factor authentication?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen, thanks for your reply, but no 2-factor for my account, any suggestions to get the error detail? I can only get a connection error in  LastCrmError and LastCrmException